# How to reload properly a webapp cached files?

Tags: javascript, caching, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, browser-cache

I can't update my Sencha Touch webapp without having to clear the browser cache to make the new version work. If I don't clear the cache manually, I get this error :

```
Error evaluating http://localhost/alpha1/app.js with message: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
```

Once I clean te cache, it works perfectly. Where could the problem come from ?

Comment: Did you build your App with sencha cmd?

Comment: The sencha cmd production build, yes.

Comment: See the https://stackoverflow.com/a/44280812/2935802

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `update` property for app.js to `full` in app.json:

```
{
    "path": "app.js",
    "bundle": true,  /* Indicates that all class dependencies are concatenated into this file when build */
    "update": "full"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know how to configure the generation of the cache.appcahe file by sencha cmd ?

Comment: By default, only index.html is put under CACHE MANIFEST. I would like to add app.js without having to do it manually after every build