# Disable caching for ExtJs app

Tags: javascript, caching, extjs, extjs5, sencha-cmd5

We have a ExtJS 5.01 app built with Sencha cmd 5.0.1.231.

The issue we are facing is that browsers seem to cache the old version of our application. On looking at the network traffic on chrome when our application is served, i can see that app.js, app.css files all have ?_dc={timestamp} appended to them. Now, that tells me that every time a new version of my app is released (which updates this timestamp), the browsers should get a new version. But it seems like sometimes still the old version get served.

Is there anything else i need to do bust cache?

Thanks

Comment: Actually it should work. Does this problem occur only for some specific js's or for all? Have you this issue in production or in development environment?

Comment: The timestamp is for the request - each request should have a new timestamp (though if you've got a batch going at the same time, it might be the same).

The purpose of the cache-busting parameter is to force caches - such as proxy servers - to get a new version. Some cache servers don't respect that, though.

The fact that you're seeing a network request, though, means that the browser at least is trying to get a new version...

Comment: @yorlin seems to happen in production environment. Development is not a problem because i always have developer toolbar open in chrome which i think disables caching

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it why "sometimes" the browser is caching your files, even when caching is disabled by default. I even force the framework to use cache whenever possible, by putting this peace of code in my `app.js`:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    disableCaching: false
});
```

While developing I open up my DevTools and set [`Disable cache (while DevTools is open)`](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/settings). This will not allow Chrome to cache files.

But it could be that in your `app.json` you are forcing "caching" into your local storage by setting `"update"` or `"appcache"`. Check your localstorage and your app.json to verify.

Comment: Thanks.. In my app.json i have got appcache:{"cache" : ["index.html"]}. Do you think this be causing the caching issue?

Comment: I would suggest you generate a test app and compare it with the one you've already got. Out-of-the-box it should not give you any problems, only when you made changes to it..

Answer (score 1):

Set the update property for app.js to full in **app.json**:

```
{
    // Path to file. If the file is local this must be a relative path from this app.json file.
    "path": "app.js",

    "bundle": true,  /* Indicates that all class dependencies are concatenated into this file when build */

    // If 'update' not specified, this file will only be loaded once, and cached inside
    // localStorage until this value is changed. You can specify:
    //   - "delta" to enable over-the-air delta update for this file
    //   - "full" means full update will be made when this file changes
    "update": "full"
}
```

Disable the cache in extjs so browser will get data from server. To do that, add the following **app.json** file.

```
"production": {
    "cache": {
        "enable": false
    }
}

"css": [
    {
        // this entry uses an ant variable that is the calculated
        // value of the generated output css file for the app,
        // defined in .sencha/app/defaults.properties
        "path": "${build.out.css.path}",
        "bundle": true,
        "update": "full"
    }
],
```