# ExtJS 6 app.js does not updates after new production release

Tags: extjs, extjs6.2

We are using Extjs 6 and we are using `sencha cmd` to build our application.

We are facing one issue. Every time we release production version of our application like 6.3 to 6.4, bundled `app.js` does not get updated and browser take that file from `(from disk cache)`. So every time we have to tell our users that  please clear your browser's cache after you got new release. `That's annoying`.

This is my app.json file.

```
"output": {
        "base": "${workspace.build.dir}/${build.environment}/${app.name}",
        "page": "index.html",
        "manifest": "${build.id}.json",
        "js": "${build.id}/.js",
        "appCache": {
            "enable": false,
            "update": "full"
        },
        "resources": {
            "path": "${build.id}/resources",
            "shared": "resources"
        }
    },
"production": {
        "output": {
            "appCache": {
                "enable": false,
                "path": "cache.appcache"
            }
        },
......
"cache": {
            "enable": false 
        }
...
```

Comment: See the https://stackoverflow.com/a/44280812/2935802

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found solution:

```
"js": [
        {
            "path": "app.js",
            "bundle": true,
            "includeInBundle": false
        }
    ],
.....
"output": {
        "base": "${workspace.build.dir}/${build.environment}/${app.name}",
        "page": "index.html",
        "manifest": "${build.id}.json",
        "js": "${build.id}/app_${app.version}.js",
        "appCache": {
            "enable": false,
            "update": "full"
        },
        "resources": {
            "path": "${build.id}/resources",
            "shared": "resources"
        }
    },
....
```

This will not include `app.js` file in production build and create new `app.js` file with version appended at last to it like: `app_6.4.js`.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two options to solve your issue:

**Customize app.js filename**

```
        {
            "production": {
                "output": {
                    "js": "${build.id}/app_${build.timestamp}.js"
                },
                "cache": {
                    "enable": true
                },
                "js": [
                    {
                        "path": "${build.id}/app.js",
                        "bundle": true,
                        "includeInBundle": false
                    }
                ],
          "output": {
            "base": "${workspace.build.dir}/${build.environment}/${app.name}",
            "page": "index.html",
            "manifest": "${build.id}.json",
            "js": "${build.id}/app_${app.version}.js",
            "appCache": {
                "enable": false,
                "update": "full"
            },
            "resources": {
                "path": "${build.id}/resources",
                "shared": "resources"
            }

        }
    }
```

With this, you get every time you build your app an new file name for `app.js`.

**Add static cache parameter**

```
  {
        "production": {
            "loader": {
                "cache": "${build.timestamp}"
            },
            "cache": {
                "enable": true
            }
        }
    }
```

With this solution ExtJs will append a `?_dc=12345678` parameter to the `app.js` request. This parameter stays the same until your next build.

Comment: I have tried both .In first: it tries to find exact file name in application so gives error and in second option: it appends "_dc" in request but still browser cache that file so not working at all.

Comment: Which version of Sencha Cmd do you use? I've tried it with version 6.2.2.36 (ExtJs 6.2.1).  Classic oder modern toolkit?

Comment: @RonakPatel Here is my full slightly simplified `app.json`: https://gist.github.com/astepin/fb1e95f753e9057570cf86e79179a48f

Comment: Require little change in app.json but your answer help me to +1